# Is enriching an Azure AD B2C Token with extra claims using an Azure Function app possible?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

I am attempting to set up an Azure B2C instance, I want to enrich the token with extra claims using an API Connector.

Can I use an Azure Function app function as the API?

I can't see anyway to do this using the Authentications allowed - the API Connector only seems to allow Basic (username/password) or Certification authentication. Whilst the Function App requires a x-functions-key in the header.

Am I heading down the wrong path with this? Should I use a simple API?

Comment: You should be able to use a Function. You can put the key in the URL. Then you have the additional Basic/Certificate authentication check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@juunas got it right in the comments.

```
https://<myfunctionApp>.azurewebsites.net/api/GetClaims?code=<mykey>
```